# R tidyverse Table Presentation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm converting statistical analyses scripts from SPSS into R, when it comes to outputting tables though I keep coming up against issues. 
I've recently began using the tidyverse package and so would ideally like to find a solution that works with that, but more generally, I would love to be pointed towards some indepth table-training for **R** if there is such a thing.

Anyway...Here is the table layout I want to replicate:

[image]

Essentially it's a freq

Here is some script for some sample data:

```
i <- c(201:301)
ID <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
i <- 1:2
Category1 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
Category2 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
Category3 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID, Category1, Category2, Category3)
```

Now I've tried this:

```
IDTab <- df %>%
            mutate(ID = as.character(ID)) %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            summarise(C1_1 = NROW(Category1[which(Category1 == 1)])
                     ,C1_2 = NROW(Category1[which(Category1 == 2)])
                     ,C1_T = NROW(Category1)
                     ,C2_1 = NROW(Category2[which(Category2 == 1)])
                     ,C2_2 = NROW(Category2[which(Category2 == 2)])
                     ,C2_T = NROW(Category2)
                     ,C3_1 = NROW(Category3[which(Category3 == 1)])
                     ,C3_2 = NROW(Category3[which(Category3 == 2)])
                     ,C3_T = NROW(Category3))
```

However this seems ridiculously manual, and will obviously increase in workload as more variables/levels are included. Not to mention that really, I've created a data frame of the table I want, instead of a table from the data frame, and all of the categorising comes from the naming convention, rather than any actual data structure.

As I said... recommendations for hardcore **R** table training are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make pretty tables, have a look at the likes of `knitr::kable`, `pander::pander`, `ztable::ztable`, and `xtable::xtable` (in rough order of increasing versatility).

The data processing example below won't give you the nested table format you are looking for, but it should scale better than your current code, and will get you the data you want.

```r
# Make dataframe
set.seed(1234)
i <- c(201:301)
ID <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
i <- 1:2
Category1 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
Category2 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
Category3 <- sample(i, 200, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID, Category1, Category2, Category3)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Get the count by 'Level' (1 or 2) per 'Category' (1, 2 or 3) for each ID
df2 <- df %>%
    # Gather the 'Category' columns
    gather(key = Category,
           value = Level,
           -ID) %>%
    # Convert all to character
    mutate_each(funs(as.character)) %>%
    # Group by and then count
    group_by(ID, Category, Level) %>%
    summarise(Count = n())

# Get the total count per 'Category' (1, 2 or 3) for each ID
df3 <- df2 %>%
    # Group by and then count
    group_by(ID, Category) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
    # Add a label column
    mutate(Level = 'total') %>%
    # reorder columns to match df2
    select(ID, Category, Level, Count)

# Finishing steps
df4 <- df2 %>%
    # Bind df3 to df2 by row
    rbind(df3) %>%
    # Spread out 'Level' into columns
    spread(key = Level,
           value = Count)

# Tabulate
knitr::kable(head(df4), format = 'markdown')

|ID  |Category  |  1|  2| total|
|:---|:---------|--:|--:|-----:|
|201 |Category1 |  1| NA|     1|
|201 |Category2 | NA|  1|     1|
|201 |Category3 | NA|  1|     1|
|202 |Category1 |  2| NA|     2|
|202 |Category2 |  1|  1|     2|
|202 |Category3 |  2| NA|     2|
```

(thanks to Jenny Bryan for the `reprex`)